# sorted value in column of dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, sorting, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe inclusion of 2 columns. I am trying to sort values in both columns, but it doesn't work. In txt file these aren't hedear, I add it when they added.

I attached a picture of code and columns.

```
df_reference = pd.read_csv(
  "reference.txt",
  delim_whitespace=True,  # any whitespace separates data
  names=["x", "y"],  # column names
  index_col=False    # no index
)

df_reference.sort_values(by=['x','y'], inplace=True,
               ascending = [True, False])
print(df_reference)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7AU8.png)

Comment: show `df_reference.info()`

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 5000 entries, 2487 to 0
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   x       5000 non-null   float64
 1   y       5000 non-null   float64
dtypes: float64(2)
memory usage: 277.2 KB

Comment: How exactly is it not working as expected?

Comment: Can you supply us with a sample of the dataframe? so we can test it for our own